# TAB break for line split in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, line-breaks

I am attempting to run a python program that can run a dictionary from a file with a list of words with each word given a score and standard deviation. My program looks like this:

```
theFile = open('word-happiness.csv' , 'r')

theFile.close()

def make_happiness_table(filename):
   '''make_happiness_table: string -> dict
      creates a dictionary of happiness scores from the given file'''
   with open(filename) as f:
      d = dict( line.split('    ')  for line in f)
   return d

make_happiness_table("word-happiness.csv")

table = make_happiness_table("word-happiness.csv")
(score, stddev) = table['hunger']
print("the score for 'hunger' is %f" % score)
```

My .csv file is in the form

```
word{TAB}score{TAB}standard_deviation
```

and I am trying to create the dictionary in that way. How can I create such a dictionary so that I can print a word such as 'hunger' from the function and get its score and std deviation?

Comment: if the fields are separated by TABs, then it's not really a "CSV" ("comma-separated values"), is it? If it were actually separated by commas, you could use the csvreader class which handles the process of turning csv's into dictionaries

Comment: @mfrankli you can use csvreader to read file delimited by any char, there is an option for that

Comment: ah interesting, never knew that! makes sense, though (in which case it would be the best bet for this application, I imagine?)

Comment: I made some edits, you can reedit the question, if something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def make_happiness_table(filename):
   with open(filename) as f:
      d = dict()
      for line in f:
         word,score,std = line.split() #splits on any consecutive runs of whitspace
         d[word]=score,std # May want to make floats:  `d[word] = float(score),float(std)`
   return d
```

Note that if your `word` can have a `tab` character in it, but you're guaranteed that you only have 3 fields (word, score, std), you can split the string from the right (`str.rsplit`), only splitting twice (resulting in 3 fields at the end).  e.g. `word,score,std = line.rsplit(None,2)`.

As mentioned in the comments above, you can also use the `csv` module to read these sorts of files -- `csv` really shines if your fields can be "quoted".  e.g.:

```
"this is field 0" "this is field 1" "this is field 2"
```

If you don't have that scenario, then I find that `str.split` works just fine.

---

Also, unrelated, but your code calls `make_happiness_table` twice (the first time you don't assign the return value to anything).  The first call is useless (all it does is read the file and build a dictionary which you can never use).  Finally, `open`ing and `close`ing `theFile` at the beginning of your script is also just a waste since you don't do anything with the file there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure your word will not have space, you can just split the line e.g.

```
word, score, stddev = line.split()
```

But if word can have space use tab char `\t` to split e.g.

```
word, score, stddev = line.split('\t')
```

But for a very generic case when word may have tab itself use the csv module

```
reader = csv.reader(filename, dialect='excel-tab')
for word, score, stddev  in reader:
    ...
```

and then you can create dict of word and score, stddev e.g.

```
word_dict[word] = (score, stddev)
```

Comment: How does csv know to split `'wordstart\twordend\tfoo\bar'` into only 3 fields?  I assume in that 'generic' case, you still need to mess with the datafile in order to quote `wordstart` and `wordend`.  In that case, to avoid needing to quote the datafile, I'd use `line.rsplit(None,2)`.  Of course, if you have multiple fields which can have tabs, you're out of luck and you'll need to quote the datafile and use `csv`.

Comment: @mgilson it is assumed that data file would be properly quoted, if it is not quoted how do we even know what is a word except to split it at tabs, csvreader can do whatever excel like program can do while reading a tab delimited file

Comment: Right, that's my point.  There is no completely general case here.  You need to assume *something*.  Either quoting, or only 1 field can have additional tabs, or no fields can have tabs ...

Comment: @mgilson using csv to read is the generic case because it handles all the valid possible scenarios

Comment: Almost, but not quite.  Assume you know the file has 3 fields and the first (or last) field can have an additional tab (no quoting).  You can't handle that without post-processing the output of CSV (as far as I know), but you can with `str.rsplit` or `str.split` (for first and last respectively).  It's a corner case, but not an extremely uncommon one (it's the reason `str.split` accepts a `maxsplit` argument).  My point here isn't that `str.split` is *better* than `csv` -- Only that they are different.  `str.split` can do things `csv` can't, and vice-versa.